# running mysqlbinlog on other server

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

When I "playback" the statments from binary, the Load data statment fails for obvious reason.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/SQL_MB-80-2' REPLACE INTO TABLE some_table
```

How do I make sure that the data is consistent even if I run the extract of the binary files onto a different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While extracting the binary statements, I need local-load parameter

```
mysqlbinlog /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.* --start-datetime="2010-02-03 15:55:38" --local-load='tmp/' > tocentral.txt
```